# Under heavy load, client connecting to a socket.io may miss the first packet with node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am on Node.js v4.1.1 and working with socket.io

when client connected to server socket and start exchanging packages at that time first packet missed on server.

have you guys any idea what is the reason behind this? Please note that we have around 900 connection at a time.

```
var http = module.exports = require('http');
var app = module.exports = express();
var httpsOptions = {
   key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
   cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.crt')
};
var Server = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app);
var io = module.exports = require('socket.io').listen(Server);
io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling", "web socket", "polling", "htmlfile"]);
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket)
{
   client.on('msg', function(request)
   {
      console.log("event get --> " + request);
   });
   client.on('error', function(exc)
   {
      console.log("ignoring exception: " + exc);
   });
   client.on('ping', function(request)
   {
      client.emit('pong', request);
      client.removeListener('ping', function() {});
   });
   client.on('disconnect', function(reason)
   {
      console.log("socket disconnect " + reason);
   });
});
```

Comment: are u using rabbitmq for sending this package..?

Comment: yes i use rabbitmq and redis

Comment: then may be there is issue of same name of queue which you are use for server, it mean when you create server at that time you give some name of queue, check this first.

Comment: are u checking ulimit of server.?

Comment: we increase ulimit up to 10000  and this issue come when client connect to socket and send first packet. after all packet get by server.

Comment: You will have to show us your code for us to have an idea what would cause this.  It sounds more like you may be sending a packet before the connection is complete or something like that.

Comment: android , ios  and flash client send first packet after socket connected but server not get that packet but if client send that packet after some time delay(2-3 seconds)server get that packet.

Comment: Is there any handshake process remaining between client and server?

Comment: Yes, there is a handshake process for webSocket.  You can see the handshake [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers).  That's why you can't send data UNTIL you get a connect message from socket.io.  I asked earlier to see your code so we can advise you how to properly wait for connection before trying to send a message.

Comment: please check my code and tell me what is improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case actually error not in socket or node.js. Error in mongodb , mongodb take so much load so all event's are late. Also new connection take load in sign up process.we just increase the configuration of mongodb and all working well.